# How to move file pointer

Tags: ruby

I need to move a pointer in an open file. How can I do something like this?

```
File.open('example.txt', 'a+') do |f|
  f.move_pointer -1
  f.write 'end'
end
```

In my example I need to replace the last character with my text

**Update**
I managed to complete the task but it looks verbose and ineffective:

```
File.open('example.txt', 'r+') do |f|
  contents = f.read[0...-1]
  f.rewind
  f.write contents + 'end'
end
```

Comment: `IO#seek` is what you need, I think.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/ is down atm:(

Comment: @leemour can you give a brief non-technical description of what you want? May be something good we can advice.

Comment: I want to replace last character/last few characters in a file with other characters. What is the most efficient and beautiful way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try `f.seek(-1, IO::SEEK_END)`.

(I found this on http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3/index.html)

**Edit**

I was able to overwrite the last (non-linebreak) character of a newline-terminated file this way:

```
File.open('example.txt', 'r+') do |f|
  # go back 2 from the end, to overwrite 1 character and the final \n
  f.seek(-2, IO::SEEK_END)
  f.write("end\n")
end
```

Comment: That didn't work. It writes my text at the end of file instead of replacing text no matter the offset value